# MySQL is it safe to use static numbers in an auto increment column

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have an auto-incremented ID field in a table. It is at 13321. If I have some products I want to insert and use the rows at 15,000 to 15,500.

I have queries in a web application that can insert new data. The queries all allow the system to generate the "id" field like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ('','value1', 'value2','value3')
```

If I insert my static data using 15000 to 15500 then reset my auto-increment id back down to 13322 will it be safe when the system gets to 15000? Will MySQL know to skip to 15501 ?

Comment: On top of the provided answer, you should NEVER manually "allocate" a primary key to a record. It must always be generated by MySQL. It appears that you're doing these inserts to maintain some sort of a sequence. **That is not what primary key is for**. Now, you might think that I'm exaggerating but I assure you - I am not. What you're doing will destabilize your dataset, hurt the performance and kill many other things that are related to concurrency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you enter the values 15000 to 15500 the AUTO_INCREMENT property of the table will be set to 15501. Afterwards you cannot reset the property back to 13322 (or any other value less than or equal to 15500). [Quote from MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value is
>   less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and
>   the current sequence value is not changed.

The *Will MySQL know to skip to 15501* portion of your question therefore becomes irrelevant.